# Using dependency injection with a required default constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I have a constructor for my class that simply takes a configuration object that returns the default connection string for my project.

```
    public AllMidContext(IConfigurationAccess configAccess) 
        : base(configAccess.GetDefaultConnectionString())
    {}
```

Entity framework complains when I try to update my database because it requires a default constructor (no parameters).

I am using Structure map and my configuration code looks like this:

```
public class GAPDLRegistry : Registry
{
    public GAPDLRegistry()
    {
        For<IAllMidContext>().Use<AllMidContext>();
        For<IDataContextAccess>().Use<DataContextAccess>();
        For<IConfigurationAccess>().Use<ConfigurationAccess>();

        For<ITournamentRepository>().Use<TournamentRepository>();
    }
}
```

I can't think of a way to have a default constructor while still injecting my dependencies.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad. In this case please include which DI framework you are using and your configuration code for the DI framework.

Comment: How does entity framework complain? Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 0):

add this source to your code

```
public AllMidContext() :    base(ConfigAccess.GetDefaultConnectionString())
{}

[Inject]
public IConfigurationAccess ConfigAccess
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need DI for this.

EntityFramework uses an instance of [IDbConnectionFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbconnectionfactory(v=vs.113).aspx) to allow loading the connection string from the configuration file. So, in your application configuration file you should have an element like this:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
    </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

If your database is a SQL Server database just take a look at [SqlConnectionFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.sqlconnectionfactory(v=vs.113).aspx) and use that in the config file.

Otherwise you can create a separate class and use it as a connection factory:

```
public class CustomConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public CustomConnectionFactory(string connectionStringName)
    {
        _connectionStringName = connectionStringName;
    }

    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
        return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
}
```

And you can use that in the config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationDB" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>

<defaultConnectionFactory type="Your.Class.Namespace.CustomConnectionFactory, YourAssemblyName">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="ApplicationDb" />
    </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```